# What is the "Attempting HD" icon when placing calls?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, calls, htc-one, sprint

I have an HTC One with Sprint, and I recently updated to Android 5.0.2.  After the update, my calls now say "Attempting HD" in the corner.  I tried googling for "attempting hd android", "attempting hd htc one" and "attempting hd sprint" with poor results. What is this?  Can I disable it if I don't want it?

[image: Attempting HD]

Comment: Basically, AFAIK, it is voice over LTE. It is a higher quality voice transmission. In order for it to be successful, both parties have to support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This icon comes from [Sprint's HD Voice feature](http://support.sprint.com/support/article/FAQs_about_HD_Voice_from_Sprint/3b348589-81a4-452d-8758-cd47d7ddb952).  The "Attempting HD" icon appears in all calls, but the feature only activates on Sprint-to-Sprint calls where both devices are supported.